# Python Homebrew Error with Pip

Tags: python, pip, homebrew

I installed homebrew and 
    which python
gives /usr/local/bin/python . However when I type which pip I get/usr/local/bin/pip and not the desired /usr/local/share/python/pip

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For my python 2.7.6 installation:

My pip is installed to: `/usr/local/bin/pip`
What makes you think it should be installed to `/usr/local/share/python/pip`?

Are you seeing a problem when you try and use `pip install (whatever)`?

Answer (score 0):

A linux command must be in a bin directory so you have no problem. Pip should be store in `/usr/local/bin/pip` not in `/usr/local/share/python/pip`.